# Css in Jquery with after and before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

Why does this snippet not work on a button? How can I do it correctly?

```
$('div.button:after').css({
    display:'none'
})
```

Comment: Jquery does not work for pseudo elements as they are not in the DOm.

Comment: I answered something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21032999/1937302

Comment: I am still amazed that no one is asking OP that what is the output OP wants? or what is the motto of asking this question?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot select pseudo elements using *inline* CSS, think like the the way you cannot write `:hover` styles *inline*.

What jQuery does with `.css()` is it injects the styles *inline* so you cannot change a pseudo element using `$('div.button:after').css()`.

---

The simple way to achieve that is by using say [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method..

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">Hello</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button:after {
    content: " Hide this using jQuery";
    color: red;
}

.hide_btn_pseudo:after {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div.button').addClass('hide_btn_pseudo');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hTL8/)

Inorder to show the element, you can remove the `class` back, using [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't. Because it is a pseudo-element.

[Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

But you can do this instead:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("div.button:after { display:'none'; }", 0);
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.display= 'none';
```

Check the link for special IE notes.

Comment: Actually, it's not a pseudo-class, it's pseudo element...the two are different.

Comment: You're right! I changed it.