# Styles for all Globally pseudo element like :before?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

```css
div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;

}

div:before{
content:'';
display:block;
background:red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:90%; top:0;
}

*:before{
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div><div>
<div><div>
<div><div>
<div><div>
<div><div>
<div><div>
```

I want to write a styles for all :before and after elements during an accessibility  mode so i am not getting it.

For example: if we wanna write style for all elements we use- *{property:value;}

like that i want to write a style for all the :before and after elements a style .

```
*:before{
 background:blue;
 }
```

this code doesn't work.

Please help out.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032481/change-the-style-of-before-and-after-pseudo-elements

Comment: @Temani Afif read my question properly please

Comment: It's done and also did the same on the answer you accepted ... you, did you read the duplicate question and found that it's not a duplicate? if yes, tell me why

Comment: yes i read my question is about pseudo class and how to apply styles for all of them once not about specifity of the divs and all.

Comment: @Temani Afif i think you read answer and marked my question as duplicate

Comment: no need to read the answer. You are asking why your code isn't working and the answer is about specifity thus the duplicate .. pseudo element play no role here, you will face the same issue even if you will target common elements. Your question is about an X requirement which a unique requirement and this requirement leads to an Y issue which is very known and common issue explained in the duplicate. We close the question based on Y not X

Comment: oh ho you bought maths in this chill bro .

Comment: what ever i got solution for selecting all pseudo class do what ever you want. But i still wont agree your duplicate question no way relate to mine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*' is the universal selector that matches every element in your dom. It is possible to extend this selector call with pseudo selectors like :before and :after.

So you can use: `*:before, *:after {...}`
See this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPRgmL

EDIT:

Your code does not work because of the specificity of your universal selector.

'div' has a higher specificity than '*' so div wins here.
See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: thats not working

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: So what you really want is to overwrite the styles for all pseudo selectors. If the selectors aren't nested too deep than you could use something like this: html body *:before { ... }

Comment: hey dude i didnt voted down some one else. ok what is not working i mentioned . how could u say that i voted