# Make image responsive. Make it fit to div

Tags: html, css

I found this code on https://thecodeplayer.com/index.php/walkthrough/3d-thumbnail-image-hover-effect and I want to make the image both responsive and whenever I change an image, the image has to scale to the div.
I tried to set: `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` but it did not work. Is it because the HTML does not contain `<img>` tags? As I'm trying to learn I would appreciate any advice you have for me on how to solve this.

```css
    /*custom font - Montserrat*/
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
    /*basic reset*/
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    /*forcing the body to take 100% height*/
    html, body {min-height: 100%;}
    /*a nice BG*/
    body {
        background: #544; /*fallback*/
        background: linear-gradient(#544, #565);
    }
    
    /*Thumbnail Background*/
    .thumb {
        width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 70px auto;
        perspective: 1000px;
    }
    .thumb a {
        display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;
        /*double layered BG for lighting effect*/
        background: 
            linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), 
            url("http://thecodeplayer.com/u/m/i1.png");
        /*disabling the translucent black bg on the main image*/
        background-size: 0, cover;
        /*3d space for children*/
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .thumb:hover a {transform: rotateX(80deg); transform-origin: bottom;}
    /*bottom surface */
    .thumb a:after {
        /*36px high element positioned at the bottom of the image*/
        content: ''; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; 
        width: 100%; height: 36px;
        /*inherit the main BG*/
        background: inherit; background-size: cover, cover;
        /*draw the BG bottom up*/
        background-position: bottom;
        /*rotate the surface 90deg on the bottom axis*/
        transform: rotateX(90deg); transform-origin: bottom;
    }
    /*label style*/
    .thumb a span {
        color: white; text-transform: uppercase;
        position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; width: 100%;
        font: bold 12px/36px Montserrat; text-align: center;
        /*the rotation is a bit less than the bottom surface to avoid flickering*/
        transform: rotateX(-89.99deg); transform-origin: top;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    /*shadow*/
    .thumb a:before {
        content: ''; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        box-shadow: 0 0 100px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        transition: all 0.5s; 
        /*by default the shadow will be almost flat, very transparent, scaled down with a large blur*/
        opacity: 0.15;
        transform: rotateX(95deg) translateZ(-80px) scale(0.75);
        transform-origin: bottom;
    }
    .thumb:hover a:before {
        opacity: 1;
        /*blurred effect using box shadow as filter: blur is not supported in all browsers*/
        box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        /*pushing the shadow down and scaling it down to size*/
        transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(-60px) scale(0.85);
    }
```

```html
<!-- Container -->
    <div class="thumb">
        <!-- Image -->
        <a href="#">
            <!-- Label -->
            <span>Three-eyed Robot</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: *Is it because the HTML does not contain <img> tags?* yes, the image is a background so its size depend on the size of the div (not the opposite)

Comment: How can I make it work then?

Comment: the trick is meant to work with background because it's applied to 2 elements (note the use of inherit)

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032481/change-the-style-of-before-and-after-pseudo-elements